# DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED Adwords

Tags: google-ads-api

Good day guys,

Please, I am working on a project that requires setting up Google Adwords account in order to use the API. I am using the Python Client Library. I am getting a DEVELOPER_TOKEN_NOT_APPROVED error when I run my test application.

After a lot of research on the issue, I figured maybe I didn't set up the production and test accounts properly which I am still struggling with. I really hope you can put me through the process as I am running against time.

Looking forward to your help

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need Developer Token from production account, but until approval is pending you need authorize API call only for test AdWords account. You need two different Google accounts. You must get Refresh Token after login to your another Google account for testing purpose.

More info: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/accounts-overview#test_accounts