# Python: Google Ads API Error (TargetingIdeaService INVALID_SEARCH_PARAMETERS)

Tags: python-3.x, google-ads-api

I am trying to access the Google Adwords API, as described in their help-file via following sample code:

```
from googleads import adwords
client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()

targeting_idea_service = client.GetService('TargetingIdeaService', version='v201809')

selector = {'ideaType': 'KEYWORD',
           'requestType': 'IDEAS',
           'requestedAttributeTypes': ['KEYWORD_TEXT',
                                       'SEARCH_VOLUME',
                                       'CATEGORY_PRODUCTS_AND_SERVICES'],
           'paging': {'startIndex': '0',
                      'numberResults': '100'
                      },
           'searchParameters': [{'xsi_type': 'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter',
                                 'queries': ['cats']}]
           }

page = targeting_idea_service.get(selector)

print(page)
```

However, when I try to call the API, following error occures:

```
zeep.exceptions.Fault: [TargetingIdeaError.INVALID_SEARCH_PARAMETERS @ selector.searchParameters.searchParameters[0]; trigger:'RelatedToQuerySearchParameter']
```

Any idea what could cause this error?
In my googleads.yaml file (which is called properly, following parameters are set:

```
# AdWordsClient configurations
adwords:
  developer_token: 
  client_id:
  client_secret:
  refresh_token:
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be late but this error is because you have not mentioned the **client_customer_id** in your googleads.yaml. Once you add that there will be no such errors

Comment: Thanks. I'd also like to add that `client_customer_id` should be the one of your test account if you don't have an approved developer token. Otherwise you'll be getting [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44002242/developer-token-not-approved-adwords). For details about client_customer_id see [here](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/first-api-call#client_customer_id).